# Pages equation editor: default code

Tags: macos, pages, latex

For math homework I use Pages and the equation editor with LaTeX. 
I want to use LaTeX macros to make writing equations more efficient, however if I have to enter in all the macro definitions each time I open the equation editor that would defeat the purpose. Is there any way to configure the equation editor to automatically load a bunch of default code each time you open it? I want to be able to type a keyboard shortcut and have the editor open up pre-loaded with a bunch of LaTeX macros that I've defined in the past, so that I can get to typing in an efficient environment right away.

Comment: Sorry that I don't know the answer to your question but I thought it was not possible to use LaTeX macro commands, i.e. the \newcommand and \renewcommand commands, in the Pages equation editor. Which macro commands have you been using so far in the equation editor in Pages?

Comment: Just from testing it out before posting the question, i found that \newcommand works. For instance, if 
`\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}` is at the top, then I can use `\R` anywhere below. \renewcommand does not appear to work